# How to keep original keybind aswell as well as a new one in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

So i have an ahk script to write letters with macrons for Latin words. When you press tilde and a vowel; it types that vowel with a macron. My only problem is removes the function of the tilde key, except typing macrons. adding a ~ to keep the original keybind makes it so when i hit tilde and a vowel, it types tilde and a long vowel. How do i fix this? (this is supposed to replicate the Maori keyboard, but that was too tedious)

```
` & a::
send, ā
return

` & e::
send, ē
return

` & i::
send, ī
return

` & o::
send, ō
return

` & u::
send, ū
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `` `::` `` to your script and backtick (`` ` ``) will fire when you release the key and tilde (`~`) will fire on press.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use

**Hotstrings**

```
aa := Chr(257)

:?O:`a::
Send, %aa%
Return
```

Typing `` `a ``then pressing an ending character (like Space) creates `ā`.

• The "O" is an Option which omits the ending character (such as an unwanted Space).

• The "?" is an Option which allows the hotstring to be triggered inside of words, so you can type `` pra` `` then a Space and it will become `prā`.

• Using Hotstrings instead of Hotkeys will keep the functionality of the Tilde key unchanged.

• By default, the backtick (`` ` ``) is used as the AHK escape character. For this Hotstring to work properly, the escape character should be changed. Example:

```
#EscapeChar \
```

> My version of your script:
>
> ```html
> #EscapeChar \
>
> ; lower case graphemes
>
> aa := Chr(257)
> ee := Chr(275)
> ii := Chr(299)
> oo := Chr(333)
> uu := Chr(363)
> yy := Chr(563)
> ae := Chr(230)
>
> ; upper case graphemes
>
> upper_aa := Chr(256)
> upper_ee := Chr(274)
> upper_ii := Chr(298)
> upper_oo := Chr(332)
> upper_uu := Chr(362)
> upper_yy := Chr(562)
> upper_ae := Chr(198)
>
> ; Hotstrings
>
> :?O:`a::
> Send, %aa%
> Return
>
> :?O:`a`::
> Send, %upper_aa%
> Return
>
> :?O:`e::
> Send, %ee%
> Return
>
> :?O:`e`::
> Send, %upper_ee%
> Return
>
> :?O:`i::
> Send, %ii%
> Return
>
> :?O:`i`::
> Send, %upper_ii%
> Return
>
> :?O:`o::
> Send, %oo%
> Return
>
> :?O:`o`::
> Send, %upper_oo%
> Return
>
> :?O:`u::
> Send, %uu%
> Return
>
> :?O:`u`::
> Send, %upper_uu%
> Return
>
> :?O:`y::
> Send, %yy%
> Return
>
> :?O:`y`::
> Send, %upper_yy%
> Return
>
> :?O:`ae::
> Send, %ae%
> Return
>
> :?O:`ae`::
> Send, %upper_ae%
> Return
>
> >
> ```
>
> The above snippet saves the true ASCII values of the characters to variables (as to avoid compatibility issues), rather than trying to print the characters *directly* through "Send".

Other Options (and more information on Hotstrings) can be found in the [Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) AutoHotkey documentation.